# ImageMagick "new Imagick" not working on PHP server

Tags: php, imagemagick

My site's hosted on Bluehost, and the installation seems to be correct, but I can't use basic functions.  I'm sure this stems from a very basic misunderstanding of the environment, and apologies for that.

The following fails with a `(Server 500 error)`

```
$im = new Imagick('test-image.jpg');
```

Yet this works:

```
exec("convert test-image.jpg -thumbnail 50x50 test-thumbnail.jpg 2>&1", $array);
```

The output from `exec("convert -version", $out, $rcode);` yields:

> Version return code is 0 
>   Version: ImageMagick 6.7.9-10 2012-10-05 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
>   Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
>   Features: OpenMP

While this check for installation....

```
if(extension_loaded('imagick')) {
    echo 'Imagick Loaded';
}
```

Prints that:

> imagick not installed

Adding web server log:

> [26-Feb-2016 10:57:16 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so: undefined symbol: php_checkuid_ex in Unknown on line 0 
>   [26-Feb-2016 10:57:16 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/magickwand.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/magickwand.so: undefined symbol: php_checkuid in Unknown on line 0 
>   [26-Feb-2016 10:57:16 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mailparse: Unable to initialize module 
>   Module compiled with module API=20060613 
>   PHP    compiled with module API=20100525 
>   These options need to match 
>    in Unknown on line 0 
>   [26-Feb-2016 10:57:16 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/magickwand.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/magickwand.so: undefined symbol: php_checkuid in Unknown on line 0 
>   [26-Feb-2016 10:57:16 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Imagick' not found in [...]/public_html/create_layout.php on line 6

Comment: 500 error almost always means check your web server log

Comment: thanks, just added the error log to the post...

Comment: Looks like you need to recompile imagick with the correct PHP version.  The API versions don't match.  Since this looks to be a shared host, it's probably time to open a support ticket.

Comment: awesome, will do and thank you so much!